# Testing for regression coefficient equal to 0

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, standard-deviation, regression-coefficients

I usually take a look at the diagonal elements of the matrix $(X'X)^{-1}$ and the $MSE$ in order to determine the standard deviation of the regression coefficients. I encountered a problem from a practice test that has a negative entry in the diagonal for the matrix $(X'X)^{-1}$. Can this be possible?

This is the problem
[image]

I am testing for $\beta_3=0$, which in order to do, I would need to take $\frac{\hat{\beta_3}}{SE(\beta_3)}$, but the negative number in the diagonal of the inverse matrix throws me off.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is this a homework?

Comment: No, this is an old practice exam, and my only question is about the standard error for the regression coefficient. I use the diagonal element of the inverse matrix provided, but it has a negative entry, so this would not make sense.

Comment: This might help https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96327/how-to-interpret-p-value-of-regression-coefficient-which-is-nearly-0?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

$\boldsymbol{X}^{\prime}\boldsymbol{X}$ is positive semi-definite.  Hence, for any vector $\boldsymbol{v}$, $\boldsymbol{v}^{\prime}\boldsymbol{X}^{\prime}\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{v} \ge 0$.  If we let $\boldsymbol{v}$ denote a standard basis vector, then this inequality implies the diagonal elements must be non-negative.  There is a typo in the problem.